# Deleting files from target folder with maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

is it possible to to delete files from target folder in maven project? I have swagger CSS file and i want to replace it with my modified version. When i try to copy .txt file to target folder it works, but when i change to .css file its not replacing the old file. Is it even possible to copy CSS files with maven plugin? My plugin:

```
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resource-one</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/css</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>main.css</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance for every answer.

Comment: What about `mvn clean`?

Comment: I've tried it, but didnt work. In which phase should i do this?

Comment: Or can i modify css file in target folder with maven plugin?

Comment: @AlbertAlbatros I cannot really follow you. `mvn clean` deletes all files in the target folder.

Comment: Why is the maven-resources-plugin explicitly configured instead of using the default...

Comment: @JFabianMeier yes but i want to delete only that one file